# Run gradle tests using image from badass-runtime plugin

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, build.gradle, jlink

I am building the javafx with `configuration = "compileOnly"` so no native javafx modules are packed in the jar.

```
javafx {
version = "13.0.1"
modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.web', 'javafx.swing', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.graphics' ]
configuration = "compileOnly"
}
```

Then I am building a runtime image with the "Badass Runtime Plugin" (https://github.com/beryx/badass-runtime-plugin) with the platform javafx modules added to each jdk.

```
runtime {
options = ['--compress', '2']
modules = [
'jdk.httpserver',
...
'javafx.controls',
'javafx.web',
'javafx.swing',
'javafx.fxml',
'javafx.graphics'
]

targetPlatform('linux-x64', "$projectDir/jre/linux/jre_x64")
targetPlatform('windows-x64', "$projectDir/jre/windows/jre_x64")
//targetPlatform('mac-x64', "$projectDir/jre/mac/jre_x64")
}
```

I am now attempting to get the gradle tests to run using the jre created by the runtime plugin because otherwise they crash due to not finding the javafx modules.

How do I set the runtime for the gradle tests but not the compiler?